# i'm not able to get modal box for my gallery images

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic, modal-dialog

I'm doing a dynamic site in php. This is the code of my gallery. I dont know what went wrong. I'm not able to get the modal box on clicking my gallery images. Can someone please help me?

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementsByClassName("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementsByClassName("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal span.onclick = function() { modal.style.display = "none"; }
```

```html
<?php                                       
 require_once("admin/config/connection.php");
 $proname="";
 $query1="select * from products_tb";
 $resource1=mysql_query($query1,$connection);
 $result1="";

 $id="";
 while($record=mysql_fetch_array($resource1))
 {
      $pid=$record['pid'];
      $img="uploads/".$record['proimg'];
      $proname=$record['proname'];
      $result1.="<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 mrgn_less prd'>
     <img style='width:300px;' id='myImg' class='modal-content'   src='$img' '>
 <div class='myModal modal'>
   <span class='close'>&times;</span>
   <img class='modal-content img01' >
   <div class='caption'></div>
 </div>
      <br>
    </div>";    
 }
 ?>
<?php  echo $result1;?>
```

Comment: `src='$img' '>` One `'` too much here. Where do you trigger your modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your JavaScript code as below

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementsByClassName("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementsByClassName("caption");
img[0].onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "block";
  modalImg[0].src = this.src;
  captionText[0].innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

when you use 'getElementsByClassName' it will return the object of html element So you need to use [0] to get the html element from that object.